# How many dogs can talk in Family Guy

Tags: character, family-guy

Brian in Family Guy is an anthropomorphic dog, meaning he is able to speak. Until the episode "Life of Brian", I assumed that he was the only animal who could speak consistently (other animals speak on one off occasions for comedy).

> Then [Vinny](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Vinny) came along and changed everything.

So that got me thinking, "How many dogs can talk?" and "If Vinny died before Brian came back from the dead would there be another dog who could replace Vinny, who would still be able to talk?"

So that's my question.

Has Seth MacFarlane ever stated if there are any other dogs/animals that can talk *consistently*?

Comment: Does the giant chicken couple count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, multiple dogs can talk. Another one that has in multiple episodes is Brian's  gay cousin Jasper in L.A., whom has a full time job and even gay married a human. Most animals have a variation in how much they can talk and who can understand them, because Family Guy runs on the rule of funny.

Answer (score 3):

I remember Brian, Vinny, cousin Jasper, and I also remember an episode where peter bought a dog because Brian was getting old and I think his name was New Brian. I can't think of any others off the top of my head.

Comment: Meg also talks.

Comment: In a flashback, there was an older dog that they had before Brian, but in that very memory, they were taking him to the vet to be put down